# Find substrings in JavaScript string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I need code that will find substrings in an array of strings. This will find complete strings:

```
var categories = [ "msn.com", "http://gmail.com", "word2" ];
found = $.inArray('http://gmail.com/example', categories);
alert(found); // TRUE
```

But I want this to be true also:

```
var categories = [ "msn.com", "http://gmail.com", "word2" ];
found = $.inArray('gmail.com/example', categories);
alert(found); // FALSE
```

Comment: What are you expecting here? Your array doesn't contain any entry equal to string `gmail.com/example`. You have to define what means `similar` string

Comment: `gmail.com/example` and `http://gmail.com/` the same domain, i want to  return True in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) method for finding the text.

```
var categories = [ "msn.com", "http://gmail.com", "word2" ]
var Item = "gmail.com";

var found = jQuery.grep(categories, function(value, i) {      
  return value.indexOf(Item) != -1
}).length;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ9rL/6/)

Comment: @Down Voter: Can you tell me why downvote here?

Comment: not my downvote but maybe because almost duplicate of my earlier answer :o)

Comment: ok, no problem (I am not see your answer before my, sorry for duplicate) :)

Answer (score 2):

update to this:

```
found = $.inArray('gmail.com/example', categories) !== -1;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EE8kp/)

---

According to the docs `$.inArray()` returns the index of the found elem and if not found it will return `-1`.

So if you are interested in a boolean value then you can try as above.

Comment: This would search for the exact matches.. http://jsfiddle.net/ec2VB/ But OP's need is completely different. I did not DV.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes that is as similar as `.indexOf()` but seems like a confusing question...??

Comment: Yes, but when i want to search `gmail.com/example`  i want to give me True because (`gmail.com`) was in array

Comment: No that is not in the array!

Comment: so how in another way do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are looking for a string which is not present in your categories array. Your sample string is also larger than the string in categories

Try this instead:

```
// this will return the matching value...
var categories = [ "msn.com", "http://gmail.com", "word2" ],
    myString = "gmail.com";

found = $.grep( categories, function ( value, i) {
   return (value.indexOf( myString) >= 0)
});
// found is non-empty array if match
```

Comment: Yes, but when we search `http://gmail.com` it return false.

Comment: Try grep - see extended answer

Answer (score 0):

to search match element from array Jquery offered 2 types of function

```
jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )
```

and

```
jQuery.grep( array, function [, invert ] )
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)...

```
// this will return the matching value...
var categories = [ "msn.com", "http://gmail.com", "word2" ],
    myString = "gmail.com";


found = categories.reduce( function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
    return (previousValue >= 0) ? previousValue : (currentValue.indexOf( myString) >= 0) ? index : -1 ;
}, -1);

// found is index of first match
```